# flutter error: Because "flutterApp" depends on sqlflite any which doesn't exist version solving failed

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I am following a tutorial to make a Note Keeper Application, so I did as he said and added these dependencies in pubspec.yaml:
**dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
sqlflite: any
path_provider: any
intl: ^0.16.1**

he used intl: ^0.15.7 , but I changed it because it didn't work.
the prblem is that it's just keep showing these messages and loading forever when I press "**get packages**"

**[note_keeper] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in note_keeper...

Because note_keeper depends on sqlflite any which doesn't exist (could not find package sqlflite at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1**

could you help me and tell what to do please? :( !

Comment: There's no such thing as the  "sqlflite" package. The package you want is "sqflite" (as in s-q-flite).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I didn't note this till you tell me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dependencies: 
  flutter: 
    sdk: flutter 
  sqflite: ^1.3.1+1 // check the spelling of sqflite you have used `sqlflite` instead
  path_provider: any 
  intl: ^0.16.1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, I think that it will take me long time to note this typo by myself.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? It's about sqflit versions, what is the differences between 0.16.1 and 0.15.7?  And why did you change the sqflite from any to 1.3.1+1?

Comment: You were trying to import mismatch package in your pubspec file. There is sqflite package and you were sqlflite.